# Replace Multiple strings in multiple yaml file using python

Tags: devops

I want to replace set of lines with another set of lines in yaml file using python

Input File :
http:
paths:
- path: /ps9-api-ta
backend:
serviceName: item-in-api-ta
servicePort: 8080
Output File :
http:
paths:
- path: /ps9-api-ta
backend:
services:
-Name: item-in-api-ta
-Port: 8080

Any help will be appreciated.